# JsonResponse return string object instead of json in symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm trying to return an json object from controller's route

```
return new JsonResponse($result);
```

It returns

```
string(36) "e91a6865-b2a8-4b7d-9351-2eac29f7aa30"
{
   //data
}
```

How can I get rid of the `string(36) "e91a6865-b2a8-4b7d-9351-2eac29f7aa30"`?

Comment: symfony 4 != symfony 3.4. that being said, looks to me like you have a var_dump somewhere.

Comment: No.Actually I'm calling this route via postman

Comment: how you're calling it is completely besides the point. I expect your code to have a `var_dump(`/`dump(` somewhere. you probably should look for it

Comment: Thanks @Jakumi. There is no var_dump.I've already checked

Comment: Well what can I say, the `string(36) "..."` is exactly the output a stray var_dump would produce. It might even be in a different file. or something fishy is going on somewhere else. however, it doesn't have anything to do with the JsonResponse. you can check by returning an empty Response, probably.

Comment: You're right. Thanks !!. You save my time. I became puzzled

Comment: You're welcome ;o)

Answer (score 1):

a `string(36) "e91a6865-b2a8-4b7d-9351-2eac29f7aa30"` or something similar, that wasn't added to the `JsonResponse`, usually is caused by a stray `var_dump`/`dump` call *somewhere* in the code base (but in a part that gets evaluated).

Essentially what happens: the `var_dump`/`dump` is called and it produces the output, and afterwards the output from the Response object (be it the JsonResponse or some other Response) is appended to that.

Options to handle this:

- remember where you put those calls ;o) (works most of the time)
- do not commit any var_dump/dump/dd calls to version control ever (and always do version control!), you'll find the calls easily in the git diff.
- run `grep -nr dump src` in the project root (on linux obviously, replace `dump` by `dd` if appropriate), this should find the relevant locations in code.

However, overall it's a rather benign source of irritating output.